hide bottom toolbar of Power Bi Dashboard
I created a site page in which I used embed option to embed my Power Bi Report. Now I want to hide the bottom section as shown in the image.

How can I achieve this?

Have you tried the OOTB Power BI Report webpart? Are you using an iframe or SharePoint embed URL?

I am using an iframe.

It's weird thought, I've tried multiple embed options but i'm unable to get that section on any of them. Are you using the embed webpart?
